# Braintree & Taxamo integration, how to do it right?

Tags: braintree, taxamo

Yes, Braintree and Taxamo have a couple of widgets facilitating their integration, but the way they work they are tied to the process of *authorization* of a credit card while what the tax services are interested in are SETTLED transactions (i.e. what is actually billed from the client at the end of the day),

settled transactions aren't the same thing as authorized transactions, voids, IO problems in API communication, client-side software bugs, even credit card company policies (chargebacks, presentment rejections etc) result with what is authorized not being equal to what is settled / billed,

special world of pain continues when you consider the complex formulas for mid-cycle subscription updates (proration), discount and addon calculations and the fact that none of my subscription API calls done using the sandbox don't have a `transaction` object (so I don't know the amounts being billed from the client),

meaning I have to reimplement a bunch of advanced logic done by Braintree to deduce what the client will see on his bank statement and hope to have gotten everything right, or have IRS on our back -_- (in Croatia companies get blocked over 1-3 euro imbalances in the tax reports)

So the question, am I missing something here?

1. is there a simple way to submit to Taxamo only settled transactions?
2. does maybe the sandbox and mock webhooks behave differently than production, is it possible that `Subscription` API calls and webhooks in production return a `transaction` object and that I just don't see it?
3. does the current Braintree and Taxamo integration at least "kind of work in practice 100% of the time" and I'm worrying too much?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Taxamo integration, but regarding question 2, the Braintree [subscription response object should include an array of transactions associated with the subscription](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/subscription/ruby#transactions)

Comment: Wow, thank you :D so, basically, I should store the number of transactions observed so far on my side and post unknown ones to taxamo...

Answer (score 3):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Braintree and Taxamo don't have an official integration package (the widgets available are not supported by Braintree, and Braintree had no hand in developing them). However, the two can be, and often are, used alongside each other. Because there's no official integration, the two integrations don't interact with one another, and the logic concerning when any action in Taxamo should take place in relation to an action in Braintree is up to a user to implement.

With that in mind, there's no 'out-of-the-box' solution to submit only settled transactions to Taxamo. Braintree does offer [settlement batch summary reports](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/reporting/settlement-batch-summary), which contain the transactions that settle every night. Using the information there, you could submit your transactions to Taxamo every night alongside the settlement batches. However, be aware that transactions don't always settle immediately, so there will be a gap between the time that you submit a transaction for settlement and the time you submit the transaction to Taxamo.

Alternatively, you could store the transaction in Taxamo immediately and keep track of the [transaction key that Taxamo generates to reference the tranasction](https://www.taxamo.com/apidocs/api/v1/transactions/docs.html#top). Then, if anything happens that prevents the transaction from settling, you can [delete that transaction in Taxamo](https://www.taxamo.com/apidocs/api/v1/transactions/docs.html#DELETEkey).

These are just two options to consider for an open-ended problem. As always, you should evaluate your business needs carefully, and do whatever you believe will work best.

As BladeBarringer mentioned in the comments to your question, [the subscription response object does contain an array of transactions](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/subscription#transactions) that you can reference. The most recent transaction is always at index [0] of that array.

Comment: Just a pointer - if you decide to integrate with Braintree directly, you could listen for webhooks and save those Disbursement batch transaction ids. This is when you're getting those funds (and what tax authorities are interested in).